# Define and send a JSON object array

Tags: asp.net, javascript, json

I'm looking for a way to define and send a JSON object array.  I've figured out how to define a single JSON object, turn it into a string and send it, but what about an array of this type?  Probably something simple I'm overlooking...

```js
var myColumnSetting = {
  "ColumnName": name,
  "ColumnIndex": index
}
```

convert it to a string

```js
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myColumnSetting, false);
```

Comment: Your example is an object, not an array. Regardless, `JSON.stringify(something)` should work fine. What is it returning? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myColumnSettings = [{"ColumnName": name, "ColumnIndex", index}, {"ColumnName":othername, "ColumnIndex":otherindex}]
```

would be like an array of columnsetting objects. Is this what you mean?